# Any ways to calculate exact time between two timestamp with timezone

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert, timestamp

is there any way in oracle to calculate the difference between two time stamps value with time zones in oracle sql plus as it is not possible to use timestampdiff or datediff inside oracle.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following in case you need the number of milliseconds between two timestamps:

```
  create or replace Function msecBetween
   (ts1 timestamp with time zone,
    ts2 timestamp with time zone,
    numDec number default 0
   )
  Return Number is
    i INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(3) := ts2 - ts1;
  Begin
    return round (
      +     extract( day    from i )*24*60*60*1000
      +     extract( hour   from i )*60*60*1000
      +     extract( minute from i )*60*1000
      +     extract( second from i )*1000
    , numDec);
  End;
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the trouble. I don't quite understand how this function works. But when i execute it on my oracle sql developer program it gives me error of ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 29 Column: 1

Comment: Hi, sorry - I forgot "create or replace" in front of function... Note that to create the function in SQL*Plus you'll need to enter / after the last line.

Answer (score 4):

Just subtract them:

```
SQL> select (systimestamp + 1) - systimestamp from dual;

(SYSTIMESTAMP+1)-SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000000 23:59:59.884789
```